# Is #ifdef MACRO equivalent to a comment

Tags: c, comments, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

Assuming that MACRO is not defined, are these equivalent

```
#ifdef MACRO
    Not valid C or C++ code
#endif

/*
    Not valid C or C++ code
*/
```

In GCC 4.7.1, it seems to be equivalent but are there preprocessors that do more?

Comment: if `MACRO is not defined` then **YES**, code will not compile in both case, preprocessors are use for **conditional compilation**, if defined true then code compiles else not

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "not valid C or C++ code".

Text inside a *comment* does not have to conform to most of the rules of the language.  It isn’t even tokenized.  This is perfectly valid:

```
/* This comment doesn't contain a valid sequence of preprocessing tokens
   (because of the apostrophe).  */
```

The only rules it does have to obey are the ones that control where the comment ends.  People regularly get tripped up by backslash-newline in line comments (in fact, SO's syntax highlighter used to get this wrong!)

```
// Line comment with ascii art ending with a \
   Oops! This line is commented out too!
```

and less often (if only because every C tutorial warns you about this) by block comments not nesting:

```
/* you can't nest /* block comments */ these words are not commented */
```

On the other hand, text inside a "skipped" preprocessor conditional "group" *does* have to conform to some of the rules of the language.  The exact words of the standard (C99 §6.10.1p5) are

> Each directive’s condition is checked in order. If it evaluates to false (zero), the group
> that it controls is skipped: directives are processed only through the name that determines
> the directive in order to keep track of the level of nested conditionals; the rest of the
> directives’ preprocessing tokens are ignored, as are the other preprocessing tokens in the
> group.

There are two important bits.  First, the text *is* tokenized, so it *does* have to be a valid sequence of preprocessing tokens.

```
#if 0
This skipped conditional group doesn't contain a valid sequence of
preprocessing tokens (because of the apostrophe).
#endif
```

is a syntax error.

```
$ gcc -fsyntax-only test.c
test.c:2:37: warning: missing terminating ' character
 this skipped conditional group doesn't contain a valid sequence of
                                     ^
```

Second, directives are still partially processed "in order to keep track of the level of nested conditionals", which means you *can* do this:

```
#if 0 // forget this entire mess
    #ifdef __linux__
    do_linux_specific_thing();
    #elif defined __APPLE__
    do_osx_specific_thing();
    #elif defined _WIN32
    do_windows_specific_thing();
    #endif
#endif
```

and you *can’t* do *this*:

```
    #ifdef __linux__
    do_linux_specific_thing();
    #elif defined __APPLE__
    do_osx_specific_thing();
#if 0 // forget windows
    #elif defined _WIN32
    do_windows_specific_thing();
    #endif
#endif
```

(You won’t get an error for that last, but…

```
$ gcc -E -P -U__linux__ -D__APPLE__ -D_WIN32 test.c
    do_osx_specific_thing();
    do_windows_specific_thing();
```

… I don’t think that’s what whoever wrote it meant it to do.)

---

Many guides to the language tell you to use `#if 0` to "comment out" large regions of code that you want to disable temporarily.  They say this because block comments don‘t nest.  If you try to disable a region of code with a block comment, but there’s a block comment inside that region, the commenting-out will end prematurely and probably the code will fail to compile.  This was more important in the days when C didn’t have line comments; some projects use only line comments for commentary, reserving block comments for disabling code.

But because code inside `#if 0` … `#endif` is still tokenized, and nested preprocessor conditionals must still balance, you do have to be a little careful about where you put the `#if 0` and the `#endif`.  It’s usually not a problem, because the code used to compile before you disabled it, so it shouldn’t have anything in it to cause a tokenization error.

Answer (score 7):

In the general case, both are equivalent.

However, if your "not valid C or C++ code" contains comments, the first form will work, whereas the second won't. That's because C standard forbids imbricated comments.

```
 /* Comments /* inside */ comments are not allowed. */
```

BTW, `#if 0` is often prefered to `#ifdef MACRO` in that case.

```
#if 0
    Invalid C source code
#endif
```

See [this question](http://c-faq.com/misc/nestcomment.html).

Comment: Comments are for commenting, macros are for preprocessing-time options. There should be a *valid* C code inside such macros. at least, valid in certain circumstances. unmatched `/*` should not be there at all, `#if`ed out ot not.

Comment: and, if you are worried about unmatched `/*`, then you should be worried about `#endif`s in the middle of the "invalid C source code".

Comment: Wow, I had to actually go look up imbricate. That doesn't happen very often :-)

Comment: The MACRO way gives me a possibility to check if the block is interesting to me. Actually I will \_\_MACRO\_\_ to get into reserved namespace.

Comment: @Elazar: `#ifdef/#endif` directives can be imbricated, but comments cannot. I am not refering to "unmatched `/*`, since it doesn't work with matched `/*` neither.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are equivalent, the preprocessing stage will eliminate `Not valid C or C++ code` before the compiler proper sees the code.

Preprocessing involves the removal of comments, and code that is `#if`ed out.

But if someone compiles the code with `-DMACRO`, the `#ifdef` version gets you in trouble, better use `#if 0` to remove code via the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant part of the standard is `C11 6.10.1 Conditional inclusion /6`:

> Each directive’s condition is checked in order. If it evaluates to false (zero), the group
>   that it controls is skipped.

That means, if any of the various forms (`if`, `ifdef` and so on) evaluate to false, *no* processing of the group is done and it is totally removed in terms of later stages of processing. It does *not* get turned into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

No, in your final code, there won't be any trace of the code inside the `#ifdef`:

```
// before
#ifdef MACRO
    Not valid C or C++ code
#endif
// after
```

After precompilations:

```
// before
// after
```

There's *no* remaining code in there.

Comment: There will also be no code in the comment, so I would say yes they are both equal; both empty

Comment: It is *equivalent* but not *equal*. OP is wrong believing that the code will be placed in a comment section. What's really happening is, the code is completely stripped.

Comment: You won't even have the `// before` and `// after` comments remaining, because comments are stripped out _before_ the preprocessing phase.

Comment: Actually this is not true. Comments get removed by the preprocessor, too.

Comment: @gx_ You mean before the *preprocessing directives* phase, i.e. before processing macros and #ifs. But both phases are considered part of the *preprocessor*.

Comment: @leemes Thank you for the correction. That is indeed what I meant (sorry...)

Answer (score 0):

If MACRO is not defined they should be equivalent. A typical way of commenting out large chunks of code is usually:

```
#if 0
code(); /* possibly with comments. */
#endif
```

This allows you to disable large parts of code even when they contain comments. So it's better than normal comments for disabling parts of code.

There's a caveat though. I've run into a compiler that choked on something like this:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#nonstandardpreprocessordirective
#endif
```

Where "nonstandardpreprocessordirective" was a preprocessor directive that only works on GCC. I'm not exactly sure what the standard says about this, but it has caused problems in reality in the past. I do not remember which compiler though.

Answer (score 0):

They are close, but not completely. assuming MACRO is not defined (or assuming you are using `#if  0` as recommended in other answers here):

```
#ifdef MACRO
Not valid C or C++ code
*/  - does no harm
#endif  - oops
more invalid code
#endif
```

and comments:

```
/*
    Not valid C or C++ code
    #endif - does no harm
    */ - oops
*/
```

Comments are for commenting, `#ifdef` are for disabling *legal* code. Aarbitrary text should not reside in the source at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most pre-processors (if not all) will remove both, comments and directives evaluated to 0. The differences between the two are mostly functional.

My advice is to use directives to "comment" code (#if 0 {} #endif) and use comments just for commenting (quite logic right?). Main reasons are:

- Directives can be activated/deactivated just modifying 1 line in the code. Block comments require insertion/deletion of 2 elements in different lines of the code.
- Directives can be nested preserving the IF logic and can also contain block comments. /*Block comments*/ cannot be nested and this can be problematic when you comment big pieces of code which can contain another comments.

> ```
> #if 0
> ...
> #if 1
> #endif
> ...
> #endif
> ```

- Simple #if 0 directives can be easily converted in define or eval directives which allow a more dynamic conditional code processing.

> ```
> //Classic verbose code line comment
>
> #if 0
> //Directive verbose line or block comment   
> #endif
>
> #define verbose 0
> #if verbose
> //Convenient eval directive to turn on/off this and other verbose blocks
> #endif
> ```

- Most IDEs do not highlight syntax of comment blocks but DO highlight syntax of directive code. Same happens with other features like indentation or autocompletion. This makes the readability of /**/ blocks quite poor in contrast to the #if 0 #endif blocks. Also the edition of commented code (e.g. adding a line or fixing something) is easier with directives.