# Is the line inside the preprocessor directive correct?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

What is the difference between these two codes:

```
#define check 0

int main(void)
{
#if check
this is a normal line
#endif
return 0;
}
```

and this one:

```
int main(void)
{
/*
this is a normal line
*/
return 0;
}
```

Are they **exactly the same** ?

Comment: You know, you could just run the [code](https://ideone.com/Ua8B2n) , they are not the same.

Comment: @George your comment is like "just look at them they are not identical" :/

Comment: @Sabrina I can't imagine why the code'ud be useful but a common idiom used in place of commenting code ( code that doesn't work or needs changing ) is to use `#ifdef 0`. Anyway in the first example the code wrapped `#if check` is not compiled as `check` is false. Where as in the second, there's no macro check, so anything inside main ( assuming it's valid ) will run.

Comment: @George From when `#ifdef` gets an **integer constant** ?

Comment: Who talked about Enum ? just delete the question it will be better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is #ifdef MACRO equivalent to a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104594/is-ifdef-macro-equivalent-to-a-comment)

Comment: @Sabrina what's incorrect about `#ifdef 0` ? It does the exact same thing as `#if check` in your code, only it's more generic for others.

Comment: @George Don't waste your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "exactly the same"? Their behaviour is identical, the text is not, obviously. Care to elaborate your question?

Comment: @George You probably meant `#if 0`. `#ifdef 0` is invalid because `#ifdef`'s argument must be an identifier, not a number.

Comment: @zwol I feel sometimes that there are dumb people here. I don't know why they upvote wrong answers.

Comment: @Sabrina I find it is best to pretend everyone here is reasonable and intelligent, even if, in the privacy of my own mind, I think they aren't either.  I point out mistakes as blandly and calmly as possible, and I try not to get into arguments, and I don't make any fuss about votes ever.

Comment: @Sabrina Incidentally, I wrote a thorough answer to this question, but it's over on the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42161150/388520

Answer (score 0):

No they are not the same.

```
#define check 0

int main(void) {
  #if check
  this is a normal line
  #endif

  return 0;
}
```

This segment, when compiled, is completely dependent on the value of the preprocessed `check` value, currently at `0`. Since the sole condition for compiling the code between your preprocessing `if-endif` is the `0|1` value of `check`, at runtime, they will be the same. However, if you were to change `check` to `1`, it would compile the conditional line as well.

At compile-time, the first segment processes the `#define check 0`, where as the second, obviously, never has to and simply ignores the comment.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, except that the first code won't compile for `#define check` ;-).